Slower Data Response from GridDB
GridDB has been very useful for many freelance projects due to its fast data retrieval and horizontal upscaling. However, the stored data is scaling exponentially due to the increasing number of users in the application. A slower database response has affected the application's performance, especially during customer registration. I want to increase GridDB's performance to efficiently manage data storage and retrieval.
Following is the schema:
const userInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "BusBooking",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["user_id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
      ["username", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["email_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["login_time", griddb.Type.TIME],
      ["elapsed_time", griddb.Type.TIME],
      ["logout_time", griddb.Type.TIME],
      ["starting_location", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["ending_location", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["distance_travelled", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["time_for_travel", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});

Here is the inline query used for user registration:
query = col.query("SELECT * WHERE user_id = '{}'".format(user_id))
row_set = query.fetch(False)
for row in row_set:
    raise Exception("User with ID '{}' already exists".format(user_id))

new_row = col.create_row()
new_row.set_field_by_name("user_id", user_id)
new_row.set_field_by_name("username", username)
new_row.set_field_by_name("email_id", email_id)
new_row.set_field_by_name("login_time", login_time)
new_row.set_field_by_name("elapsed_time", elapsed_time)
new_row.set_field_by_name("logout_time", logout_time)
new_row.set_field_by_name("starting_location", starting_location)
new_row.set_field_by_name("ending_location", ending_location)
new_row.set_field_by_name("distance_travelled", distance_travelled)
new_row.set_field_by_name("time_for_travel", time_for_travel)
col.put(new_row)

print("User '{}' created successfully".format(user_id))

However, I found out that the query was inefficient, so I optimized it as follows:
query = col.query_by_key(user_id)
row_set = query.fetch(False)
if row_set.has_next():
    raise Exception("User with ID '{}' already exists".format(user_id))

However, performance improved slightly, but not significantly enough. On the other hand, before GridDB, I used Oracle Database and created indexes to solve query-related performance issues, such as quick and responsive data access and retrieval. Similarly, is it possible to create indexes in GridDB, or does GridDB manage that on its own? Furthermore, is there any other efficient option to improve GridDB's query and data retrieval performance?

Have you tried creating an index on your user_id column? https://griddb.org/docs-en/manuals/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html#create-index
